# Selection of cells must lead to a string of concatenated (ID) strings correspondent to the cells selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm developing a GIS-based application and I have organized data fro the user to search in different categories. I have arranged them in a plain UITableView.Now, every category has a correspondent ID string (f.e.: category Hospitals has an ID : f556682-de5tgh4dde-ff478).I have made two arrays: One that holds the categories and one that holds the ID strings.I think the association of the ID string to each category must be done via a NSMutableDictionary, but not sure how to do it and how to make a string that is created dynamically each time the user selects a determinate number of rows and is the result of the concatenation of the ID strings of the selected cells? I need this string to be passed to a server that depending of the string creates on the fly KML files.(The reason I need it.)This is the code I have done until now:

```
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [gisCategoryID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//gisCategoryID is an array that holds the ID strings
  NSLog(@"ID %@", [dictionary objectForKey: @"ID");
  NSLog(@"Name %@", [dictionary objectForKey: @"Name");

  NSMutableString *categString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
  for (NSMutableDictionary *categInfo in dictionary)
      [categString appendFormat: @"%@&", [categInfo objectForKey:@"ID"]];
```

I have doubts for this being the correct way because every time I select a row, the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create a new mutable dictionary from two NSArrays which hold NSStrings: iDArray and categoryArray

// these arrays already exist and contain NSStrings and have the same number of items.

NSMutableDictionary * myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:25];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < [iDArray count]; i++) {
[myDictionary addObject:[categoryArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[iDArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: First,thank you very very much for your time.Second,I understand what you are saying and I tried your code.The app does not crash anymore,so it must be fine.Also,to put the strings together, I included this in the for loop: `NSMutableString *categString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
  for (NSMutableDictionary *categInfo in dictionary)
      [categString appendFormat: @"%@&", [categInfo objectForKey:[iDArray objectAtIndex:i]]];` I think it should be right.

Comment: Yyour solution looks fine to me, so I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to concatenate the strings, but you need to use a dictionary, which associates a key string to them? Anyway, the selected cells are returned as an array using indexPathsForSelectedRows, so that's how you can find which ones.  And to dynamically create a string, you could do something like:

```
NSString * concatString = @"";
for (NSString* onestr in myArrayofString) {
  concatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",concatString, onestr];
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this works for concatenation of strings of an array, how to do this when using a dictionary?Am I doing it wrong? I am updating the question with the code I have done.

Comment: First off, the object at the index path.row a dictionary?  Put a breakpoint on the first line of code, and just before it executes it, type "po  [gisCategoryID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]" into the debugger.  It will at least tell you what kind of object is there. Second of all, just because you define categInfo to be mutable doesn't make it so.  And it doesn't look like you're changing the dictionary, so why even make it mutable?  There's a lot of your code missing, and it's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, categInfo has not to be mutable.So,I will make just an array.I typed what you said in the debugger and its type is an Array of characters.But how do you think is possible to do what I need in the proper way, to assign an ID to every row/cell?

Comment: OK.  So each object store in gisCategoryID is an array of Characters?  Yet, instead, you're assigning it into a variable that the compiler thinks is holding an NSDictionary.  This is one of the reasons why you crash, the computer thinks it has an NSdictionary, and it's really an array of characters.

Comment: It's tough to figure out what you're doing, but I'm going to add some code that let's you create a dictionary and add things to it in the following answer.